# Convert array to a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array like this a list called `ord_lst`. How can I convert it into a list.

```
[array([5029339601]), array([5029339775]), array([5029338374])]
.
.
.
.
```

Expected output

```
[5029339601 5029339775 5029338374]
.
.
.
```

What I have tried:

```
new_order_list = [item.tolist() for item in order_lst]
```

But this does not give expected output I am looking for.
Sorry this might have already been answered but the solutions did not work for me.
I would appreciate your feedback. Thanks

Comment: First, I see two duplicated lists, not a list. Please make your sample syntactically correct and consistent with your question. Second, what kind of `array` is that? A Python array? A NumPy array? Third, what have you tried and what did not work? Please add your code.

Comment: @DVZ Thanks. I have added some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is trivial, once you understand how indexing works:

```
[item[0] for item in ord_list]
#[5029339601, 5029339775, 5029338374]
```